# Orbeon - how to set values of numerous fields with one query

Tags: orbeon

I have created a database service that retrieves numerous columns.  I have successfully created the action to call other queries which passes in a parameter and displays the output in drop-down box or check boxes.  HOWEVER, with this new query I would like to set the values of 5 different fields on the form based on the single query call.  What xpath expression syntax is needed in the 'Set Response Control Values' section in order to make this work.....or is this not the right place or way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using Form Builder - in the "Set Response Control Values" section in the Actions Editor, you should set up one item for each form field to be updated, with the Destination Control drop-down specifying the form field.  So in your case you'll have 5 rows pointing to your 5 fields.

Let's assume that your query returns a single row, with the values that will go into your form fields in separate columns.  Your query results come from the database service looking like this:

```
<response>
    <row>
        <query-column-1>value</query-column-1>
        <query-column-2>value</query-column-2>
        ...
    </row>
</response>
```

So if the column name for your first item is "id", the "Set Response Control Values" entry would look like this:

```
/response/row/id
```

There is one gotcha...if a column name in the database includes an underscore, this will be converted to a hyphen in the results from the database service.  So if your column name was "asset_id" you'd put `response/row/asset-id`.

If your query returns multiple rows, you can refer to a specific row using a predicate, like so: `response/row[1]/id`